# How to save attachments and standard output with a pester unit test?

Tags: powershell, unit-testing, attachment, pester

I would like to attach files and standard output to a Pester unit test. I run pester with NUnit output format, so that it could be published to our Azure DevOps server. But it does not seem to capture any output nor let me attach files - something NUnit does allow.

Is there a built-in way to do it?